# Lightroom2 import question

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-2

I downloaded my LumixLX5 images to a location on my internal hard drive and imported them to Lightroom2. The files showed up in light room's left column, pictures in the center area as I expected. However when I returned to LR after quitting, the files were missing from the left column and I could not access the imported pix. What am I doing wrong? I have used lightroom1 a lot. My computer is a 2006 iMac.

Comment: When you imported them did you leave them where they were, or move them to be controlled by Lightroom?

Answer (score 1):

If you imported the files, they should be there.  Lightroom doesn't have a left column that lists files... my suspicion is that you're talking about Folders.  Use the Folders label on the left side and navigate to the folder that contains your images.